# Get category ID from WP

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am trying to get 2nd level category of a single Post.

A Post is under this hierarchy Sports > Football > premier league

i want to get the ID for Sport how can i do this.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all first level categories by this code for particular post

```
 $cat = get_the_category($post_id);
```

then by this one you can get child categories

```
$child_categories=get_categories(
    array( 'parent' => $cat->cat_ID )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this will work for '*nth*' level

```
$category = get_the_category(); 
$parent = get_ancestors($category[0]->term_id,'category');
if (empty($parent)) {
  $parent[] = array($category[0]->term_id);
}
$parent = array_pop($parent);
$parent = get_category($parent); 
if (!is_wp_error($parent)) {
  var_dump($parent);
} else {
  echo $parent->get_error_message();
}
```

---

Reference:

- [get_the_category](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/)
- [get_ancestors](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_ancestors)